How can I move the icon button in a container?
　
This is my container. I want to move the copy button to the right. How can I do?
This is my code.
Container(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                      "",
                  ),
                ),
                  child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: setClipboard,
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.copy,
                    ),
                  ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 15,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

I skipped my decoration of container.

Use Spacer() in b/w text and icon btn Or rather then flexible use Expanded() depending upon your use case

You just can force the text to allocate the remaining space of the row: by setting fit: FlexFit.tight which makes the flexible widget equal to Expanded widget
Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
        child: Row(children: [
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.tight,
            child: Text(
              "",
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.copy,
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      )

Note: SizedBoxs have been replaced by padding.
Or, you can put a spacer between the text and the icon button:
  Text(
            "",
          ),
          Spacer(),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.copy,
            ),
          ),

or setting Row's mainAxisAlignment to spaceBetween.
 Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
          Text(
            "",
          ),
         
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.copy,
            ),
          ),
        ]),

Hope it helps you.

As a beginner I would suggest to use sized box. For responsiveness add MediaQuery to fetch the screen width.
Container(
    child: Row(
        childrens: [
             sizedBox(width: ...), //Use MediaQuery to access the width
             IconButton(...)
        ]
    ) //end of row
) //end of container


There are multiple ways to achieve this,
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.r),
    ),
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.copy_outlined),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
 ),


here, you have to give the container width of double.infinity so
that it can capture the whole width. Then give the container alignment
of centerRight, so that it can align its child from right. and
you achieve you goal

Another way by using row,
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.r),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              const Flexible(
                child: Text(
                  "Copy",
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.copy_outlined),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),


Here, inside the container give row with mainAxisAlignment property
MainAxisAlignment.end which align its children from right, and you
achieve your goal.

I hope this will solve your issue and you can understand overall procedure.

By setting up the MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween of your Row, your copy button and text Widget will always be separated and copyButton will always stick to the left.
           Container(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [....]
                       ) //ending of Row
                 ) //container ending


Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.
